# WCF Custom Tcp binding failing to load from config file

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

Hello I have the following custom binding on a duplex WCF service that refuses to load.

```
        <binding name="CustomBinding1" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="infinite">
      <transactionFlow />
      <reliableSession maxPendingChannels="20" inactivityTimeout="00:01:00" />
      <security authenticationMode="IssuedTokenForSslNegotiated" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncryptAndEncryptSignature">
          <issuedTokenParameters tokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0">
            <issuer address="https://localhost/IdentityServer/issue/wstrust/mixed/certificate" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ws">
              <identity>
                <dns value="" />
              </identity>
            </issuer>
            <issuerMetadata address="https://localhost/IdentityServer/issue/wstrust/mex"></issuerMetadata>
          </issuedTokenParameters>
      </security>
      <binaryMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <tcpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880" connectionBufferSize="8192" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" channelInitializationTimeout="00:01:00" maxBufferSize="5242880" maxPendingConnections="20" maxOutputDelay="00:00:00.2000000" maxPendingAccepts="5" transferMode="Buffered" listenBacklog="25" portSharingEnabled="true" teredoEnabled="false">
        <connectionPoolSettings groupName="default" leaseTimeout="00:00:00" idleTimeout="00:00:00" maxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint="0" />
      </tcpTransport>
    </binding>
```

When i start the service i get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Binding 'CustomBinding' doesn't support  creating any channel types. This often indicates that the BindingElements in a CustomBinding have been stacked incorrectly or in the wrong order. A Transport is required at the bottom of the stack. The recommended order for BindingElements is: TransactionFlow, ReliableSession, Security, CompositeDuplex, OneWay, StreamSecurity, MessageEncoding, Transport.

From the documentation everything looks fine, can anyone see anything wrong with this? I know there a few element missing but they are all optional.

Thanks

Endpoint:

```
      <service name="Company.Services.SessionService" behaviorConfiguration="Release">
    <endpoint name="SessionTcp" address="net.tcp://localhost:61002/SessionService/1/Federated" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding1" contract="Company.Services.Common.Interfaces.ISessionService" />
  </service>
```

Service behaviour:

```
        <behavior name="Release">
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Always" />
      <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true">
        <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=Server.Company.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
        <issuedTokenAuthentication>
          <allowedAudienceUris>
            <add allowedAudienceUri="http://Company.com/" />
          </allowedAudienceUris>
        </issuedTokenAuthentication>
      </serviceCredentials>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="200000" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="200" maxConcurrentSessions="2000" maxConcurrentInstances="2000" />
    </behavior>
```

Comment: Can you post the full configuration?

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: The error message says `Binding 'CustomBinding'` but your configuration has `CustomBinding1`. Are you sure it complains about the binding you showed in the question?

Comment: Yes, the error means it's a custombinding type. That's not the name.